# Resolving a python array wrapped in Json with Angular.js $resource

Tags: angularjs, json, rest, controller, webapp2

I am working with webapp2 and Angular's $resource, I am having hard time finishing the job and resolving my data array from JSON format within my controller.

in my python handler, the array wrapper to JSON format is as follows:

```
self.response.write(json.encode(self.getVertices()))
```

and here is my service code in Angular:

```
angular.module('myPage').service('onServices',['$resource','$q', 
function($resource,$q){
   this.getMesh = function(){
   var Mesh = $resource('/context/actors/one',
   {}, {get: {method:'GET', isArray:true,responseType:'json'}})
   return Mesh.get().$promise.then(function(data) {
               one = data
               return one})   
}
}]);
```

and my controller code is this:

```
$scope.bck =  onServices.getMesh();
```

when I log 'data' inside the service, it shows as series of 'resource' each of which containing a row of the array. And when I log the data inside the controller, it is still in 'promise' format, which contains the series of 'resource' (array rows). I can see the data inside the promise, but I am not seeing the data in the expected format, which is JSON. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get JSON when you call the python part? Have you tried this [Python JSON docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

```
self.response.headers['content-type'] = 'text/plain'
self.response.write(json.dumps(self.getVertices()))
```